# DependencyProperty in my UserControl fails to update bound property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, wpf-controls

I have made an usercontrol that contains a TextBox with some custom behaviours and I want to bind the Text property to a property in my ViewModel.

I have isolated the problem into a sample solution and manage to update the Text property with the ViewModel property value, but when I write into the textbox and leaves the textbox my Person.Name property is not updated.

My usercontrol xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfCustomUserControlBinding.TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Control.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="readOnlyTextbox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TextBoxBase.IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBoxBase.Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                <Setter Property="TextBoxBase.Foreground" Value="#FF6D6D6D" />
                <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                <Setter Property="TextBoxBase.BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TextBoxBase.IsReadOnly" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextBoxBase.Background" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="TextBoxBase.Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Control.Resources>

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextbox}" x:Name="txtTextBoxBase" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

The codebehind code:

```
public partial class TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled
{
    public TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string)
                                                                                         , typeof (TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled)
                                                                                         ,new PropertyMetadata(OnTextChange));

    private static void OnTextChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled = (TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled) d;
        textBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled.txtTextBoxBase.Text = (string) e.NewValue;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Window where I try to get the sample to work:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCustomUserControlBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfCustomUserControlBinding" Title="MainWindow" Height="153" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <src:Person x:Key="myDataSource"/>        
</Window.Resources>
<Grid >
    <Label Content="Plain vanilla" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" />
    <Label Content="Messed up version" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,61,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,15,0,0" x:Name="txtVanlig" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <src:TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,61,0,0" x:Name="txtVrien" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

The sample value class:

```
 public class Person
{
    private string _name = "King Chaos";

    public string Name{get{return _name;}set{_name = value;}}
}
```

Thanks in advance. ;)

Edit: Adding INotifyPropertyChanged does not do the trick since the set method of the Name is not accessed when updating my custom TextBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the TextBox inside your TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled UserControl has no two-way binding to the Text property - you only update the TextBox programmatically (in the OnTextChanged handler) when your property value changes, but not vice-versa.

Why not just drop the changed handler altogether, and add a binding instead, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfCustomUserControlBinding.TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Control.Resources>        
  //...
</Control.Resources>

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextbox}"
         x:Name="txtTextBoxBase"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Don't forget to also set the DataContext accordingly:

```
public partial class TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled : UserControl
{
    public TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
                                                                                         typeof(TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem you are experiencing is caused because the `Text` dependency property of the `TextBox` inside of your custom `TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled` is actually not bound to your "ViewModel" (the `Person` class) and so when you write something in that `txtTextBoxBase` its `Text` dp is changed, but the change is not propagated back to the ViewModel.
What you can do is wire the `Text` dp of the nested `TextBox` to the `Text` dp of your custom control with:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTextBoxBase"
         Text={Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled}}} />
```

Comment: If I understod you correct, you pinpointed the problem, but your sample code did not do the trick. Therefore the bounty goes to gstercken. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: ah, yes, I've forgotten to add the TwoWay binding mode, if you add it should work with the binding I supposed, without having to "burn" your TextBoxReadOnlyLooksDisabled's DataContext in the way gstercken has suggested.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _name = "King Chaos"; 

    public string Name{
       get{
          return _name;
       }
       set{
          _name = value;
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
              PropertyChanged(this, new 
                 PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
       }
    } 
}
```

Simply your model must Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise property changed whenever your property is set, so that XAML will detect a change and refresh its value.

Comment: Thats maybe an error. But did not do the trick. When updating my custom textbox the setter to the Name property is not accessed.

Comment: Did you verify your solution before posting?

Comment: I am not obligated to test this, you are asking for help and people will point you the direction, no one is ping to test and solve your problem.